# Stored procedures with multiple parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am currently doing an assignment based on manipulating spatial data within a database.

One of the questions in the assignment requires me to create a **single** stored procedure that requires **three parameters** and will then populate one of the tables I created earlier with the data it receives.

For example;

***stored_procedure*** 'Point', '(co-ordinates)', 'Point 1'

Where;

-'Point' is either point, polygon or linestring

-'(co-ordinates)' are various co-ordinates

-'Point 1' is a description of the shape

What is the basic code behind a stored procedure like that? Obviously not wanting the full code but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server` ?

Comment: How does the basic code differ from the full code? And again: MySQL or ms sql server? The two are different products.

Answer (score 0):

i just defined the parameters as varchar
Just adapt them to your needs.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mystoredprocedure 
                 @var1 varchar(5) 
                ,@var2 varchar(5) 
                ,@var3 varchar(5) 

AS
Begin 
    INSERT INTO table_name
       VALUES (@var1, @var2, @var3); 

End
```